# karate html report in Jenkins shows everything expanded

Tags: karate

I am using karate version 0.9.6 and I'm very happy with it. I have just a minor issue:

When running tests locally, the generated html report has many steps collapsed (like POST steps etc.) which is pretty convenient because I can expand only the steps I am interested in.

When running the same tests in Jenkins however, the same html report has all steps expanded and it can be pretty confusing to zoom in to the part you want.
I am using Firefox to display the report in both cases. Actually, I have tried also with Chrome and it didn't make any difference.
Do you know anything that could affect this behavior?

I hope I expressed the issue clearly enough, otherwise I can try and provide a screenshot.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I realize now that this is probably due to Jenkins security policy not allowing Javascript... is there any workaround in case someone is not allowed to change the security policy?

Comment: I don't know about the workaround. I'm pointing you to an answer where advanced users can write custom reports in theory. see if that helps. else consider this as not supported